# use ifelse to transform a column in a dataframe and return the result

Tags: r

I just learned, `ifelse` returns a value with the same shape as `test`.

I would like to return a log transformed column from a data frame, if some logical variable is set to `TRUE`, but I only get a single value and sometimes an `NaN`.

Is there a correct way of doing this. I like the `ifelse` solution, since it is easy to read.

Here is some example code:

```
log_a <- TRUE
jnk <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4))
ifelse(log_a, log2(jnk[['a']]), jnk[['a']])
```

What I expect is `0.000000 1.000000 1.584963 2.000000` but I get a `0`.

I would like to use this result to construct another data frame in the way:

```
jnk2 <- data.frame(x=ifelse(log_a, log2(jnk[['a']]), jnk[['a']]), y=c(1,2,3,4))
```

Comment: You need `rep`  `ifelse(rep(log_a, nrow(jnk)), log2(jnk[['a']]), jnk[['a']])` as `ifelse` needs the arguments to have the same length

Comment: You are checking a single condition here instead scanning a whole vector. You just need the good old `if` and `else` as in `if(log_a) log2(jnk[['a']]) else jnk[['a']]`

Comment: @akrun akrun, you should be renamed to Flash... Nice solution! Didn't thought about repeating the boolean... Would you like to post an answer?

Comment: It's okay.  I think you  need `if` as @DavidArenburg mentioned without using the `rep`.

Comment: @DavidArenburg this is why I added my next step, since I would like to use this directly in the data frame creation. So the solution by akrun reads nicer.

Comment: ifelse does not necessarily needs arguments of same length (and you can play around this). Remind that this is a vectorized function on condition and results!

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel Can you elaborate `does not necessarily needs arguments of same length`?

Comment: I don't know what does "reads nicer" means. You can simply do `data.frame(x=if(log_a) log2(jnk[['a']]) else jnk[['a']], y=c(1,2,3,4))` or wrap it into some function.

Comment: @akrun, this is one example where dog is recycled: `ifelse(c(T,F,T,F), 'dog', c('pig', 'snake', 'bird', 'cat'))`. I would NOT advise to proceed like this, but it is possible.

Comment: @DavidArenburg you are right, I always use `if` and `else` with `{}` so I was not aware to use it without the brackets in case of just one line of code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sapply(jnk$a, function(i) ifelse(log_a, log2(i), i))

# result    
# [1] 0.000000 1.000000 1.584963 2.000000
```